# Where should I store collections of objects to facilitate DI / testing?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

I am trying to figure out where to store collections of objects that are retreived from a database that are necessary for the application to function. For example, I am trying to re-design a reporting application that uses `Report` and `Parameter` objects. These objects are stored in a database in XML format. At the simplest level, a collection of the definitions could be stored as a `Dictionary<string, string>` (object key, object definition XML).

I want to implement a factory pattern to handle the creation of these objects from their XML definitions.

```
IReport GetReport(string reportName)
IParameter GetParameter(string parameterName)
```

These methods require the factory to store the collections of reports and parameters.

So, my questions are:

1. Should the factory store the collection of objects at all or should it only be responsible for creating the objects from the definition, changing the method to `IReport GetReport(string reportDefinition)`
2. If the factory should store the objects, should I simple inject the collections into the constructor of the factory class?
3. Unit testing - If I go the route of #2, I suppose I would just inject my test collections into the factory, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can structure this in many ways which all adhere to the [SRP (Single Responsibility Principle)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

One way is as follows: have one interface, `IReportLoadingService`, with a method which takes in the report identifier, and returns the `IReport` instance.

An implementation of this `IReportLoadingService` can have an `IReportDefinitionRetrievalService` as a dependency, e.g.

```
public class ReportLoadingService : IReportLoadingService
{
    private readonly IReportDefinitionRetrievalService _definitionService;

    public ReportLoadingService(IReportDefinitionRetrievalService definitionService)
    {
        _definitionService = definitionService;
    }

    public IReport GetReport(string reportName)
    {
        var reportDefinition = definitionService.GetDefinition(reportName);
        return GenerateReportFromDefinition(reportDefinition);
    }

    private IReport GenerateReportFromDefinition(string definition)
    {
        // Logic to construct an IReport implementation
    }

}
```

The live implementation of the `IReportDefinitionRetrievalService` will access the database and return the XML. Now your `ReportLoadingService` has the responsibility of populating `IReport` instances while another service has the responsibility of actually obtaining the report definition.

For unit testing, you can create a Mock of the `IReportDefinitionRetrievalService` which does whatever you want (e.g. looking up the definition in a dictionary). Take a look at [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) for a good mocking framework. It will allow you to do things like this:

```
[Test]
public void GetReportUsesDefinitionService()
{
    var mockDefinitionService = new Mock<IReportDefinitionRetrievalService>();
    mockDefinitionService.Setup(s => s.GetDefinition("MyReportName")).Returns("MyReportDefinition");

    var loadingService = new ReportLoadingService(mockDefinitionService.Object);

    var reportInstance = loadingService.GetReport("MyReportName");

    // Check reportInstance for fields etc

    // Check the definition service was used to load the definition
    mockDefinitionService.Verify(s => s.GetDefinition("MyReportName"), Times.Once());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, I think the `IReportDefinitionRetreivalService` was the key component that I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Your application should be persistent ignorant, so your report factory (or repository would be a better term for a facade over a data store, actually it's a Data Access Object not really a repository) should not take a report definition format.

The Get method should take a unique identifier for the report (should this be report name?) and return a DTO type that has all of the values for the report entity.

You can use an abstract factory pattern to have different implementations of your repository, one that does the XML deserialization, and a mock implementation for unit tests.

Your repositories don't need to store the collections in memory if you already have a database as the data store, although you might want to add caching to your repository, which again is easier to switch out if your application is working against abstractions.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Should the factory store the collection of objects at all or should it only be responsible for creating the objects from the definition,
>   changing the method to IReport GetReport(string reportDefinition)

None of the above.  A factory is a concrete implementation selector.  It's implemented as a static method which instantiates a concrete object based upon the input.  You have done the job of decoupling correctly with an interface and a name.  Stop there.

`static IReport GetReport(string reportName)`

`IReport concreteReport = Factory.GetReport("myReportName")`

Testing a factory via a unit test is straight forward.  You can create an array of report names and check the `IReport` is the correct implementation via reflection or some arbitrary known Assertion.  Dependency Injection is a different topic alltogether.